# CSS, defining multiple class tag properties for animation

Tags: html, class, css, css-transitions

Is there a way to define the same properties for 'p', and 'h1' to 'h6' that live in the same class?

For example, I tried this:

```
div.project h1, h3, p {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: 0.8s;   
}
div.project:hover h1, h3, p {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Hoping that when I hover on any element (h1, h3, or p) within a .project class, they would behave in the same way.

However, only h1 behaves as defined.

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/4vGvv/2/)

I don't want to define a different (div.project h3) and (div.project p) separately, as it seems a bit redundant. I was hoping there to be a more elegant way about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have do define separate classes for (div.project h3) and (div.project p), but you do have to define relationships separately. This:

```
div.project h1, div.project h3, div.project p {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: 0.8s;   
}
div.project:hover h1, div.project:hover h3, div.project:hover p {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

should do the trick.

Comment: ha! I know I was missing something

Answer (score 1):

No, there isn’t a practical one. CSS Selectors Level 4 offers [the `:matches()` selector](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/selectors4/#matches):

```css
div.project :matches(h1, h3, p) {
    …
}
```

Support is not good at the moment, but there’s nothing really wrong with a simple

```css
.project h1, .project h3, .project p
```

You can also turn to a CSS preprocessor, such as Sass or [LESS](http://less2css.org/):

```css
.project {
    h1, h3, p {
        …
    }
}
```

Comment: That's a great answer too minty, but I think Yuriy answered it more precisely. Thanks